# Dojo2: How to get the child widget instance to call functions on it

Tags: dojo, children

The setup is really simple, assume this piece of code:

```
 export default class App extends WidgetBase {

     protected render() {
         return v('div', [
             w(MyCustomWidget, {}), 
             v('button', {
                 id: 'abc',
                 classes: ['btn', 'btn-primary'],
                 onclick: this.clickMe
             }, [
                 'Hello World!'
             ])
         ]);
     }

 }
```

The class `MyCustomWidget` defines now a function which I want to call from the current `App`-widget. If I do `let cw = w(MyCustomWidget, {})` I get an object with the key `instance` which contains exactly what I want. But if I use `cw.instace` TypeScript tells me, that `Property instance does not exist on type 'WNode<MyCustomWidget>'`.

So how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the guys from Dojo2 and they responded to me very quickly with:

> If you want a child widget to call a function from the parent you need pass it to the child as a property. In dojo the widget instance are never exposed.

This was also my workaround but I was not sure if this was the correct way to do it. It certainly works. Now we know.